# Decode french accent not working with utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding

I try to decode this very simple variable `b'autorite nt\\syst\x8ame\r\n'`

```
b'autorite nt\\syst\x8ame\r\n'
>>> t.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 16: invalid start byte
```

But nothing is working, it should print `autorite nt\\système` but I cannot find a way to print it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't encoded as UTF-8.  It might be cp437, or any of these: cp437, cp720, cp850, cp857, cp858, cp860, cp861, cp863, cp865 ([source](https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#8a))

```
>>> print(b'autorite nt\\syst\x8ame\r\n'.decode('cp437'))
autorite nt\système
```

Comment: is there a way to be a bit more universal ? what if the next byte is not 'cp437' encoded ?

Comment: If your bytes include text with more than one encoding  then you are going to have difficulties.  There are tools like chardet which will try to guess the encoding of a bytestring, but there's no general solution for bytes of mixed encodings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use decode with `utf-8` encoding and replacement rule.

```
t = b'autorite nt\\syst\x8ame\r\n'
t.decode('utf-8', 'replace')
```

Further reading:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html